# In Extjs, How do I see if a checkbox is checked, and then if it is checked, add that checkboxes id to an array?

Tags: php, arrays, extjs, checkbox

I am learning Extjs along with PHP and MySQL for one of my web development course in college right now, and I am very close to finishing my final project for the class and I am stuck on something as simple as a checkbox. I am more into c# programming, so my c# mindset is clashing with the necessities of ExtJS.

The program asks hospital patients a vast amount of questions about their day-to-day feelings, and I have a list of Checkboxes for common symptoms and I need to be able to check to see, once they submit the form, which symptoms were checked and add that symptoms id to the symptoms array.

Is this even close?

```
    if(headacheCheckbox.getValue()==true){
        symptoms[headacheCheckbox.getId()];
    }
```

on the Server Side I have

```
        $id=$dbh->lastInsertId();
        $symptom=$_REQUEST['symptoms'];
        while($tmp=$symptom->fetch()){
        $stmt=$dbh->prepare("insert into symptom_input (inputid, symptomid) values (?,?)");
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $id);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $tmp);
        $stmt->execute();
        }
```

and I have my ajax request in my ExtJS taking in the symptom array as a parameter like so..

```
    params: {action: 'create_input',
        symptoms: symptoms[],
        },
```

Absolutely any help/criticism is welcome.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
 $symptom=$_REQUEST['symptoms'];
```

and this line

```
 while($tmp=$symptom->fetch()){
```

do not compute.

fecth is method ffor prepared statement object  http://il2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php (when you fetchign a result set, similar to mysql_fecth_row for unprepared statements) while you have an array parsed to this variable  `$symptom=$_REQUEST['symptoms'];` So your fetch will throw an error in while

assuming that your array looks like this

```
$_REQUEST['symptoms'][112];
$_REQUEST['symptoms'][234];
```

what you need is something like this

```
  $id=$dbh->lastInsertId();
  $symptom=$_REQUEST['symptoms'];

   foreach($symptoms as $symptomid){
        $stmt=$dbh->prepare("insert into symptom_input (inputid, symptomid) values (?,?)");
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $id);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $symptomid);
        $stmt->execute();
        }
```

Also when passing a parameters

assuming that code bellow is creating an array in your JavaScript

```
if(headacheCheckbox.getValue()==true){
        symptoms[headacheCheckbox.getId()];
    }
```

you need to

```
params: {action: 'create_input',
        symptoms: symptoms //without square brackets and no comma IE7 will throw an error
        },
```

Comment: Ahh! Thanks you very much. You are definitely a major help.

If I were to define an array titled "symptoms", would it work for me to add the checkbox id like this..

symptoms.push(headacheCheckbox.getId());

Comment: @Chris Caudill no worries mate, if it worked/helped please mark the answer